# trying to get sliced image together

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a sliced image in a table and can get the first line/row ok but cant figure out code for to complete image. Each time I do it, the image goes all funny as in splits instead of putting together.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var noRows = 4;
    var noCols = 5;
    var rowRef = 1;
      function buildTable(){
      document.writeln("<tr>");
      for (var x = 0; x < noCols; x++) {
        document.writeln("<td>");
        document.writeln("<img src=");
        document.writeln("'images/pica1_r.jpg");
        document.writeln(rowRef);
        document.writeln("_c");
        document.writeln(x + 1);
        document.writeln(".jpg' /></td>");
        }
    document.writeln("</tr>");
    return;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    buildTable();
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of building the whole table in JavaScript, I'd recommend building the table in HTML, and then using `Element.innerHTML` to add the images to the relevant cells. That way you won't have to struggle with complex loops. Also, what are the names of your image files you're trying to insert? You appear to be appending the `.jpg` extension twice.

Comment: Also, the above code appears to work fine, assuming your files have the correct names: https://jsfiddle.net/3jsp7k0x/

Comment: Thank you for your help. Each pic is pica1_r1.jpg, pica1_r2.jpg and so on. Im very new to all this and still trying to understand. Took me a few days to get this far. Just cant get the images in the rows correctly. Could you please explain a little more on using element.innerHTML  it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that you have is that you're outputting the `.jpg` extension twice. In your current flow, you'd output `images/pica1_r.jpg1_c1.jpg` and `images/pica1_r.jpg1_c2.jpg` and so on.

Instead of messing with `rowref` and `_c`, I'd simply make use of string concatenation to output all of the image tag on one line, helping prevent confusion:
`"<img src='images/pica1_r" + x + ".jpg' />"`

You can even make this easier on yourself by starting your loop from `1` rather than `0` with `for (var x = 1; x < noCols + 1; x++)`.

The following will output `images/pica1_r1.jpg`, `images/pica1_r2.jpg`, etc:

```js
var noRows = 4;
var noCols = 5;
var rowRef = 1;

function buildTable() {
  document.writeln("<tr>");
  for (var x = 1; x < noCols + 1; x++) {
    document.writeln("<td>");
    document.writeln("<img src='images/pica1_r" + x + ".jpg' />");
    document.writeln("</td>");
  }
  document.writeln("</tr>");
  return;
}

buildTable();
```

In order to cover columns as well, you need to make use of a **second** loop, **outside** of your `<td>` outputs. Note that this needs to be a brand new variable (I've gone with `y`), and it needs to be based off of `noRows`.

The following will output four rows, all containing the same five images in a row. I've substituted to local image for an absolute hosted one, though simply swap the commented-out line with the image line to see it working locally:

```js
var noRows = 4;
var noCols = 5;
var rowRef = 1;

function buildTable() {
  for (var y = 1; y < noRows; y++) {
    document.writeln("<tr>");
    for (var x = 1; x < noCols + 1; x++) {
      document.writeln("<td>");
      //document.writeln("<img src='images/pica1_r" + x + ".jpg' />");
      document.writeln("<img src='http://placehold.it/10" + x + ".jpg' />");
      document.writeln("</td>");
    }
    document.writeln("</tr>");
  }
  return;
}

buildTable();
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate your help. Will give this a try

Comment: I have been playing around with code, thank you. Can get image put together on 4 rows but its the same image duplicated as in row 1. Just cant figure out how to get complete image put together on the four rows.